# NullReferenceException em código WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nullpointerexception

[image: exceção NRE no Visual Studio]

Acredito que seja um *bug* não do código, mas sim do compilador...

Quando eu comendo essa área de código, o erro sempre passa pra próxima variável, ou método.

Veja: 
[image: exceção NRE no Visual Studio]

Parte do código:

```
                grpBoxMDeck[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
                {
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, yG),
                    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(536, 340),
                    BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent,
                    ForeColor = corLetra,
                    Font = new System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily, 8.25f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
                    Text = string.Format("Elixir Médio: {0:f1} - Arena {1}+", elixirMedio, decks[i].Split('|')[1]).Replace(',', '.')
                };
                grpBoxMDeck[i].Click += (s, e) => pMelhoresDecks.Select();
                grpBoxMDeck[i].ContextMenuStrip = cmsGBMDecks[i];

                picImagemMDecks[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[8];
                byte x1 = 3, x2 = 3;

                for (byte j = 0; j < picImagemMDecks.Length; j++)
                {
                    byte copiaJ = j;
                    picImagemMDecks[i][j] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
                    {
                        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(131, 157),
                        SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
                    };
                    if (j < 4) { picImagemMDecks[i][j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x1, 15); x1 += 133; }
                    else { picImagemMDecks[i][j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x2, 174); x2 += 133; }
                    grpBoxMDeck[i].Controls.Add(picImagemMDecks[i][j]);
                }

                pMelhoresDecks.Controls.Add(grpBoxMDeck[i]);
```

Alguma solução pra esse *bug*?  Ele apareceu do nada, o código era executado normalmente, até mesmo essa última linha:

```
pMelhoresDecks.Controls.Add(grpBoxMDeck[i]);
```

Agora nem mesmo ela é executada. Já tentei fechar e abrir o Visual Studio e nada!

Comment: Nossa, o compilador existe há anos, milhões de pessoas o usam todos os dias, e ninguém tinha pego esse *bug* nele? Como você conseguiu pegar este erro? Você estudou muito programação para conseguir isto?

Comment: Onde está a declaração de `pMelhoresDecks`?

Comment: Um de seus controles não estão inicializados, estão nulos. Para vc saber qual, pressione F9 (para colocar um breakpoint) na linha do controle e confira cada um deles (parando sobre eles com o mouse, ou clicando neles e pressionando Shift+F9). Isso não é um bug no compilador, é no código mesmo.

Comment: Letícia, todos os controles são inicializados, até por que a primeira exceção aparece na declaração da variável byte x1 = 3;
Não faz sentido.

Comment: consegui resolver assim: picImagemMDecks = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[deck.Length > 10 ? 10 : decks.Length][];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimenta fazer isso:

```
picImagemMDecks[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
```

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) é assim que se cria um novo objeto `PictureBox`.

Não posso garantir que funcionará porque não temos todo o código para saber. Mas tudo leva a crer que seja isto.

Na verdade a maioria das pessoas escrevem assim:

```
picImagemMDecks[i] = new PictureBox();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/MultipleControls.cs).

E a variável `pMelhoresDecks` precisa ser inicializada com algum valor antes de usar. Se não fez isto o valor dela é nulo e nada pode ser feito com ela a não ser inicializá-la. Então tem que fazer isto antes de usar. Normalmente se faz a inicialização junto da declaração dela. Ache-a e dê um `new` alguma coisa lá.

Algumas dicas:

- Comentar um código que dá erro não faz o erro desaparecer, geralmente causa mais erros e provavelmente mais difíceis de solucionar.
- Fechar o Visual Studio não faz o erro magicamente desaparecer.
- O problema "nunca" é do compilador.
- Leia a documentação do que está usando antes de usar. Se não entender algo, vejo o que precisa aprender antes.
- Você está fazendo o acabamento de uma casa que não tem alicerce, vai tudo desabar. Primeiro entenda como as coisas funcionam, o que é cada coisa, um passo de cada vez, vai no simples, um conceito depois do outro, quando dominar algo aí você passa para a próxima. Se ficar jogando códigos que não entende não está programando e cada dia ficaria pior.

Comment: picImagemMDecks é um array bidimensional, e eu instancio ele assim: 
System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[][] picImagemMDecks;
Depois eu crio 8 imagens dentro de cada vetor...

Comment: Por que está dando exceção na instanciação da variável do tipo byte? Como descrito, o compilador está lançando uma exceção sempre na próxima linha de código. Se eu comento a linha da variável byte, ele lança uma exceção no for (byte j = 0;

Comment: Bom, vou marcar sua resposta como solução. Mas, consegui resolver assim:
picImagemMDecks = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[deck.Length > 10 ? 10 : decks.Length][];

Estava faltando instanciar a quantidade de vetores dessa array bidimensional
Grato pelo comentário.